# Order By causing my query to run really slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query as follows

```
select *
from incidents
where remote_ip = '192.168.1.1' and is_infringement = 1
order by reported_at desc
limit 1;
```

This query at the moment takes 313.24 secs to run.

If I remove the `order by` so the query is

```
select *
from incidents
where remote_ip = '192.168.1.1' and is_infringement = 1
```

then it only takes 0.117 secs to run.

The reported_at column is indexed.

So 2 questions, firstly why is it takings so long with this order_by statement and secondly how can i speed it up?

**EDIT:** In response to the questions below here is the output when using explain:

`'1', 'SIMPLE', 'incidents', 'index', 'uniqueReportIndex,idx_incidents_remote_ip', 'incidentsReportedAt', '4', NULL, '1044', '100.00', 'Using where'`

And the table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `incidents` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `incident_ip_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_ip` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `is_infringement` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `messageBody` text,
  `reported_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Formerly : created_datetime',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueReportIndex` (`remote_ip`,`host_id_1`,`licence_feature`,`app_end`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueRemoteIncidentId` (`remote_id`),
  KEY `incident_ip_id` (`incident_ip_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `incidentsReportedAt` (`reported_at`),
  KEY `idx_incidents_remote_ip` (`remote_ip`)
)
```

Note: i have omitted some of the non relevant fields so there are more indexes than fields but you can safely assume the fields for all the indexes are in the table

Comment: Could be partial answer.  Without ordering, your query just retrieve any 1 record.  With ordering, it need to sort the data first, and retrieve the 1st record

Comment: *"The reported_at column is indexed."* -- it depends how it is indexed.  Put [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) in front of the query and put the output in the question. Also put the table structure (the `CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: maybe you need to create an index for your table so as to improve the performance when searching.

Comment: could you also try an ascending sort (for comparison - I have found this to make a huge difference in past examples)

Comment: It seems like this problem is because of `MySQL's inability to do late row lookups`. For details you can refer below links: - [MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

Comment: Wait a minute. Your second query does not have a `limit` clause? You can retrieve all records in <1s? How many records are there?

Comment: @Prisoner yes agreed but the difference in time is quite considerable and the query without the order by only returns 3 records so i wouldn't expect it to take 313 secs to sort 3 rows

Comment: @axiac edits are above

Comment: @Rodney i tried the asc sort and it made a remarkable difference so now only takes about 3 secs. The only issue is i need the latest record not the oldest

Comment: @w0lf it depends on the ip address specified but the one I was testing it on only returned 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `EXPLAIN` reveals that, because of the `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL decides to use the `incidentsReportedAt` index. It reads each row from the table data in the order provided by the index and checks the `WHERE` conditions on it. This requires reading a lot of information from the table data, information that is scattered through the entire table. Not a good workflow.

#### Update

The OP created an index on columns `reported_at` and `report_ip` (as suggested in the original answer, see below) and the execution time went down from 313 to 133 seconds. An improvement, but not enough. I think the cause of this still large execution time is the access to table data for each row to verify the `is_infringement = 1` part of the `WHERE` clause but even adding it to the index won't help very much.

The OP says in a comment:

> Ok after further research and changing the index to be the other way round (`remote_ip`, `reported_at`) the query is now super fast (0.083 sec).

This index is better, indeed, because the `remote_ip = '192.168.1.1'` condition filters out a lot of rows. *The same effect can be achieved using the existing `uniqueReportIndex` index.* It is possible that the original index on `reported_at` fooled MySQL into thinking it is better to use it to check the rows in the order required by `ORDER BY` instead of filtering first and sorting at the end.

I think MySQL uses the new index on (`remote_ip`, `reported_at`) for filtering (`WHERE remote_ip = '192.168.1.1'`) and for sorting (`ORDER BY reported_at DESC`). The `WHERE` condition provides a small list of candidate rows that are easily identified and also sorted using this index.

The original answer follows.
**The advice it provides is not correct** but it helped the OP find the correct solution.

---

Create an index on columns `reported_at` and `report_ip` in this order
then see what `EXPLAIN` says and how the query performs. It should work faster.

You can even create the new index on columns `reported_at`, `report_ip` and `is_infringement` (the order of columns in the index is very important).

The index on three columns helps MySQL identify the rows without the need to read the table data (because all the columns from `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses are in the index). It needs to read the table data only for the rows it returns because of `SELECT *`.

After you create the new index (either on two or three columns), remove the old index `incidentsReportedAt`. It is not needed any more; it uses disk and memory space and takes time to be updated but it is not used. The new index (that has the `reported_at` column on the first position) will be used instead.

---

The index on two columns requires more reads of the table data for the `is_infringement = 1` condition. The query probably runs a little slower that with the three-columns index. On the other hand, there is a little gain on table updates and disk and memory space usage.

The decision to index on two or three columns depends on how often the query posted in the question runs and what it serves (visitors, admins, cron jobs etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The table is quite large so it will take a while to create the new index but i will post the result when i have created it.

Comment: Just as a side note, are you able to explain why the indexes should be in that order? I would have thought the relevant records would be gathered first (incident_ip, is_infringement) then the sort of the records by reported_at. I was just wondering for future indexing.

Comment: MySQL uses indexes for both lookup and sorting. When the query contains a `LIMIT` clause, MySQL stops searching after it finds the number of rows required by the `LIMIT` clause. It decided it is better to use the index to get the rows in the correct order and stop after it finds the first one than to get all the rows, sort them and discard all but the first one. I think we should respect its decision and help it find the records faster.

Comment: The order of columns in the index is important because an index on columns `A` and `B` is also an index on column `A` but it is not an index on column `B`. You already have an index on column `reported_at`. An index on `reported_at` and `remote_ip` in this order matches the way MySQL works to resolve this query; it uses the `reported_at` column to get the order then the `remote_ip` column to filter (then the `is_infringement` column, if present, to identify the row). It is possible that an index on `remote_ip`, `is_infringement`, `reported_at` also helps.

Comment: You don't need the index `id` (it duplicates the `PK`). Also, the index `idx_incidents_remote_ip` is not needed because it is a prefix of `uniqueReportIndex`. Read more about [multiple column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on MySQL. It explains: *"If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`), you have indexed search capabilities on (`col1`), (`col1`, `col2`), and (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)."*

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. They have been very informative. So i have created the index on (reported_at, remote_ip) and the query now takes 133.647 secs so it is better but still painfully slow. The  query without the order by is 0.186 sec. I also removed the redundant indexes (id and IncidentsReportedAt).

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me (and possibly the reason that is causing the query to be slow) is that the records are ordered before the relevant records are selected. This means the millions of records in the table need to be ordered before selecting the 3 records that are required. If the ordering was done after, surely this would speed up the query loads?

Comment: Also i have been reading this article https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm which seems to suggest the ordering is done after the where clause. Although not sure if different databases execute defferent parts of the DB at different times (e.g MySQL vs MS SQL etc)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149707/discussion-between-axiac-and-sambremner).

Comment: Ok after further research and changing the index to be the other way round (remote_ip, reported_at) the query is now super fast (0.083 sec). Your answer was by far the best answer so i would like to mark it as correct but could you please edit it first to show the correct index order.